# How to Better Handle Error and Updates in Simple React-Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been reading about normalizing state that gets returned from my reducer (React-redux) and I think I understand that if I don't spread (...) the state returned, that my React app will not recognize that a state change has happened and my UI will not update.

That is, if I return some thing like:

```
data: action.payload.data     // where this is an array
```

instead of what I have below

```
...action.payload.data
```

My UI does not update (no render() called).

Assuming this is correct (which my testing seems to show), then I'm perplexed on how I can return an error condition.  What I've done below is returned isLoading and isErrored as properties in place of the single array property.

This feels ugly.  Like I'm using my return to mean one thing on success and another thing on errors.

Suggestions for a better way to do it? What am I missing?

```
export function sessionAttendee(state = {}, action) {                    
    switch (action.type) {
        case SESSIONATTENDEE_LOAD: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoading: true,
                hasErrored: false
            });
        }

        case SESSIONATTENDEE_LOAD_SUCCESS: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                ...action.payload.data
            });
        }

        case SESSIONATTENDEE_LOAD_FAIL: {
            console.log("SESSIONATTENDEE_LOAD_FAIL");
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLoading: false,
                hasErrored: true,
                errorMessage: action.error.message
            });
        }
```

Comment: Why -1 vote? I thought I explained the issue clearly and it is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` returns a new object. This will ensure that you don't mutate the previous state. There's plenty of good reasons in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/758) as to why you want to avoid mutating your state.

In regards to your statement "This feels ugly. Like I'm using my return to mean one thing on success and another thing on errors" I would say that you aren't actually using your returns to do multiple things. They always return the state object for that reducer. All that is different in the switch statements is that you're updating properties of that object.

FWIW, I've noticed that you are spreading within an `Object.assign` which is probably unnecessary. Here's how I would re-write your reducer so it would make more sense to me...

```js
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    hasErrored: false,
    errorMessage: null
    data: [],
}

export function sessionAttendee(state = initialState, action) {                    
    switch (action.type) {
        case SESSIONATTENDEE_LOAD: {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
                hasErrored: false
            }
        }

        case SESSIONATTENDEE_LOAD_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload.data
            }
        }

        case SESSIONATTENDEE_LOAD_FAIL: {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                hasErrored: true,
                errorMessage: action.error.message
            }
        }

    default: 
        return state;
    }
}
```

1. defined an `initialState` as that makes it somewhat easier to reason when reading. Not a requirement, but I find it helps.
2. switched from `Object.asssign` to using the ES6 spread operator.
3. Ensured that your action.payload.data key was actually assigned to a property on the state object, rather than just smishing it in.

Comment: Thanks @patrick  Where I'm still confused is on how to return an array of items in state this has some changes in it. If I return data:action.payload.data and one of the data items changes, my component does not re-render

Comment: OK, can you post your component? Including the mapStateToProps fn

Comment: Let me try your suggestions now and see. Sounds like you are thinking that if  an item in a data item changes then that should trigger an update.

Comment: More accurately my thinking is that the `SESSIONATTENDEE_LOAD_SUCCESS` action returns a new object, which should trigger an update as the object references have changed.